# Is there any NFT Price API available to fetch Price of a NFT from Opensea?

Tags: nft, opensea

I want to retrieve NFT price from OpenSea and LooksRare using contract address and token ID.

Is there any such API or SDK available for this purpose ?

I am not looking for opinion just a simple API for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution

[OpenSea Asset Listing API](https://docs.opensea.io/reference/asset-listings)

This API returns current listing price of a NFT

Answer (score 1):

You can try out the Alchemy `getFloorPrice` API from [these docs](https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/enhanced-apis/nft-api/getfloorprice).

---

If you want a quick test, you can make a `curl` command like this:

```shell
curl 'https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/nft/v2/demo/getFloorPrice?contractAddress=0xbc4ca0eda7647a8ab7c2061c2e118a18a936f13d'
```

(just make sure to swap out the `demo` api key for [your own Alchemy api key](https://dashboard.alchemyapi.io/signup/?a=0b17fede14), and use your desired `contractAddress`)

---

Here's a different example using javascript:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

// replace with your Alchemy api key
const apiKey = "demo";
const baseURL = `https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/nft/v2/${apiKey}/getFloorPrice`;
// replace with the wallet address you want to query for NFTs
const contractAddr = "0xbc4ca0eda7647a8ab7c2061c2e118a18a936f13d";

var config = {
  method: 'get',
  url: `${baseURL}?contractAddress=${contractAddr}`
};

axios(config)
.then(response => console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 2)))
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```

The response would look like this and shows prices from OpenSea, LooksRare, and other marketplaces:

```js
{
    "openSea": {
        "floorPrice": 90,
        "priceCurrency": "ETH",
        "retrievedAt": "2022-06-21T13:50:17.080287240Z",
        "collectionUrl": "https://opensea.io/collection/boredapeyachtclub"
    },
    "looksRare": {
        "floorPrice": 87,
        "priceCurrency": "ETH",
        "retrievedAt": "2022-06-21T15:08:59.819Z",
        "collectionUrl": "https://looksrare.org/collections/0xbc4ca0eda7647a8ab7c2061c2e118a18a936f13d"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reservoir endpoints:

https://docs.reservoir.tools/reference/getordersasksv4

They work in ethereum, polygon,... and support OpenSea, LooksRare, ...

Answer (score 0):

You can now use CoinGecko for this. They have a new NFT API:
https://www.coingecko.com/en/api/documentation